# Trying to exude part of URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to get my image to not require the ?i= in the url. I have tried a few different ways but end up with problems.

FULL URL:
http://rizimg.com/view/image.php?i=936489-NH3s5u8.jpg

What I want it to look like:
http://rizimg.com/view/936489-NH3s5u8.jpg

My current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /view/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ view/index.php\?i=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `RewriteBase /view/` if you're adding the code to `/view/.htaccess`. If not, remove it. If yes, then you don't need to specify `/view` again in your `RewriteRule`.

So, your rules should look like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /view/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$ image.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you're adding your rules to the .htacces in your root directory then use

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^view/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$ view/image.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Good to provide both versions +1

Comment: Hey there! I appriciate the reply. I am trying it now and it seems to return with a 500 internal server error. I have tried both versions and I have also done more research on things like [END]. I still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What's your directory setup? Which htaccess version are you using?

Comment: I did a little bit of test when I comment out both of the rewrite conditions, it returns not found instead of a 500.

Comment: You didn't reply to: Which htaccess version are you using? and Where have you placed the htaccess file? root or /view?